# htaccess rewrite rule with id variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I"m trying to go from

**whatever.domain.com/index.php/view/page?id=1&id=2&id=3**

to

**whatever.domain.com/page?id1=1&id2=2&id3=3**

Basically i just want to cut out the index.php/view part of the url and keep everything else the same.

The following code works if i do not have any id variables in the url

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/view/$1 [L]
```

I tried the following so that id1 id2 id3 gets passed along but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm appreciate your help on this

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/view/$1?id1=$2&id2=$3&id3=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule with `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/view/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Which URL did you use to test and what is location of .htaccess file? Are there more rules also?